# QGIS 2.16.0 - issues with styles and rearranging attribute table columns

Tags: qgis

I'm finding QGIS 2.16.0 is not honouring attribute table column order once saved styles are applied to tables edited using Table Manager/Refactor field. E.g a new column will shift to the far right in the attribute table view once a style has been applied, despite the order shown under Layer Properties -> Fields still being correct. The order will also still be shown as correct in the Table Manager/Refactor field menus. It appears to just be an issue in the actual attribute table view, and only in 2.16.0.

Is there a work around other than going back to an older version of QGIS?